# How to write Unit Test cases for AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, testing, avplayer

We are using AVPlayer and playing DRM Protected content using fairplay approach.

Now it's time for writing Unit Test cases for the player. I know how to write unit test cases to check API calls, functionality check etc.

But I'm not able to figure out what are the test cases I can write for AVPlayer to check the player functionality, content quality, audio and video output checks.

I would like to know is it possible to write Unit test cases for a Player ?  if yes, what will be the better way of doing it ??

Comment: Do you want to test the AVPlayer itself or some component in your app that uses the AVPlayer? If the former is the case, well, maybe you should refrain from doing so. In the latter case, you should provide some code samples which illustrate what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Any code you write should/can be tested, it may not make much sense to test the audio but in projects with many collaborators, someone can at some point make a change and crashing the application the tests would help you to see that.
I had the same thoughts as you before I had to write the test cases and that led me to find your question here. I wrote test cases where I needed to test my project's audio layer.
It may not make much sense, but if you need to present a 100% tested code, it is valid.

It's a simple example.

```swift
import XCTest

class AudioPlayerTests: XCTest {

    let audioManager = AudioManager()

    func test_AudioManager_PlaySound() { 
        audioManager.playSound(named: .background, numberOfLoop: 0, volume: 1)
        XCTAssertNotNil(audioManager.audioPlayer)
        XCTAssertEqual(audioManager.audioPlayer!.numberOfLoops, 0)
        XCTAssertEqual(audioManager.audioPlayer!.volume, 1)
        XCTAssertTrue(audioManager.audioPlayer!.isPlaying)
    }

    func test_getaudio() {
        audioManager.playSound(named: .effectOne)
        let sut = audioManager.getSKAudioNode(.background)
        XCTAssertNotNil(sut)
    }
}
```